# Windows Phone: How to change time in TimePicker from C# code

Tags: windows-phone, timepicker, toggleswitch

I have defined 4 ToggleSwitch like this (copied from example). Do I have to use DataTemplate?? Now I would like to change time value in TimePicker. How do I access time_picker and change the content? Thanks a lot!

```
                <toolkit:ToggleSwitch Name="sleep_mode" Grid.Row="1" Header="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.Sleep_Mode, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Checked="fetch_sleepmode_Checked" Unchecked="fetch_sleepmode_UnChecked" Click="OnClicked">
                <toolkit:ToggleSwitch.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentControl FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Content="{Binding}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </toolkit:ToggleSwitch.HeaderTemplate>
                <toolkit:ToggleSwitch.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.Status, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}"/>
                                <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}" Content="{Binding}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.SleepMode, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneSubtleBrush}" Width="360"/>
                            **<toolkit:TimePicker x:Name="time_picker"  ValueChanged="TimePicker_ValueChanged"/>**
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </toolkit:ToggleSwitch.ContentTemplate>
            </toolkit:ToggleSwitch>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, I don't see why you even bother setting `ContentTemplate` for the `ToggleSwitch`, since no custom binding is present (e.g. to an instance-specific collection).

Instead, set the content directly and modify the `TimePicker` properties the same way - through a named reference.

On a side note - why would you even want a `TimePicker` inside a `ToggleSwitch`?

Comment: Ok, that's I was suspected why it needs ContentTemplate in the example at first time. I was trying to remove but didn't work well. But now I did it again and it works fine not. Thanks! Oh, the reason why I put timePicker inside ToggleSwitch is that I want to align timepicker with the text of toggleswitch. A bit stupid but works that for me :)